# Is match(Uri) of class UriMatcher reentrant?

Tags: android, thread-safety, reentrancy, android-contentprovider

The examples that I have seen of how to make a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) have all used the [`UriMatcher#match(Uri)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html#match%28android.net.Uri%29) method within the `insert`, `query`, `update`, and `delete` methods to easily handle all of the URI patterns that the content provider responds to (e.g.: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotePadProvider.html). This seemed okay to me until today, when I noticed on the `ContentProvider` API documentation that `insert`, `query`, `update`, and `delete` "can [all] be called from multiple threads". Additionally, the `UriMatcher` documentation says nothing about thread-safety or whether `match` is reentrant.

Do I need to worry about synchronizing calls to `match` on a shared, `static` instance of `UriMatcher` that is used within my implementations of `insert`, `query`, `update`, and `delete`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking through [the source of `UriMatcher`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/content/UriMatcher.java;hb=HEAD), it appears that multiple threads *can* call the `match` method simultaneously because the implementation of `match` only accesses the per-thread variable `uri` (the parameter), shared `String`s, and elements of an `ArrayList<UriMatcher>` (via [`ArrayList#get(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29), which is thread-safe).

`addURI` is **not** thread-safe because it structurally modifies an `ArrayList`. It is the same `ArrayList` that `match` reads from, so `addURI` cannot be called while other threads are possibly calling `match`.